# Join-heavy MySQL query gets slow when sorting by datetime, not slow sorting by ID

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, datetime, mariadb

I have a MySQL (actually MariaDB) query which is running much slower and falling back on filesort when I try sorting by a DATETIME field (`sighted`) instead of the primary key. I have an index on `sighted`, but for some reason it does not seem to be using it. How can I index this table so that it can be sorted by the DATETIME field efficiently?

```
select 
    user_id , t.name, f.value, y.name 
    from posts p 
        left join taxon_sightings t on (t.post_id = p.id) 
        left join fields f on (f.foreign_id = t.id) 
        left join fieldtypes y on (y.id = f.fieldtype_id) 
    group by p.id 
    order by p.sighted desc 
    limit 10;
```

When I sort by the `sighted` DATETIME field:

```
MariaDB [dbase]> explain [yadda yadda, as above]
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+------------+---------+--------------------------------+------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys | key        | key_len | ref                            | rows | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+------------+---------+--------------------------------+------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | p     | ALL    | NULL          | NULL       | NULL    | NULL                           | 1759 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t     | ref    | post_id       | post_id    | 4       | dataportal_test.p.id           |   12 |                                 |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | f     | ref    | foreign_id    | foreign_id | 4       | dataportal_test.t.id           |    6 | Using where                     |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | y     | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY    | 4       | dataportal_test.f.fieldtype_id |    1 | Using where                     |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+------------+---------+--------------------------------+------+---------------------------------+
```

Compare to when I sort by ID:

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+------------+---------+--------------------------------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys | key        | key_len | ref                            | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+------------+---------+--------------------------------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | p     | index  | NULL          | PRIMARY    | 4       | NULL                           |    1 |             |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t     | ref    | post_id       | post_id    | 4       | dataportal_test.p.id           |   12 |             |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | f     | ref    | foreign_id    | foreign_id | 4       | dataportal_test.t.id           |    6 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | y     | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY    | 4       | dataportal_test.f.fieldtype_id |    1 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+------------+---------+--------------------------------+------+-------------+
```

Comment: That sounds like an index problem. Did you add an index to the datetime column so that it can optimize the query?  Mind sharing the table definition?

Comment: Yes, I did, but it's not using it (which is confusing!).

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the tables.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can.  The only trick that I can think of is to try this:

```
select user_id, t.name, f.value, y.name 
from posts p left join
     taxon_sightings t
     on (t.post_id = p.id) left join
     fields f
     on (f.foreign_id = t.id) left join
     fieldtypes y
     on (y.id = f.fieldtype_id) 
group by p.sighted, p.id 
---------^ very important
order by p.sighted desc 
limit 10;
```

Then include an index on `posts(sighted, id)`.  The `group by` with the `order by` might take advantage of the index.  If you are lucky . . .

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `p.id` is unique in `posts`, let's get rid of `GROUP BY p.id`.  I assume the only reason for its existence is because the `JOINs` are inflating the row count?

Get rid of `LEFT` unless you need it.

```
SELECT  x.user_id, t.name, f.value, y.name
    FROM  
      ( SELECT  id, sighted
            FROM  posts
            -- No GROUP BY needed if id is UNIQUE
            ORDER BY  sighted DESC
            LIMIT  10 
      ) AS p
    JOIN  taxon_sightings t ON (t.post_id = p.id)
    JOIN  fields f ON (f.foreign_id = t.id)
    JOIN  fieldtypes y ON (y.id = f.fieldtype_id)
    GROUP BY  p.id
    ORDER BY  p.sighted DESC, p.id DESC;
```

And (as Gordon suggests), have `INDEX(sighted, id)`.